# Calling malloc and realloc from within a function gives unexpected results

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, realloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char _getline(char *s)
{
    char c;
    s = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));

    int i;
    for (i = 0; (s[i] = getchar()) != EOF && s[i] != '\n'; ++i)
    {
        s = (char *)realloc(s, (i + 1) * sizeof(char));
    }
    c = s[i];
    s = (char *)realloc(s, (i + 1) * sizeof(char));
    ++i;
    s[i] = '\0';
    return c; 
}

int main()
{
    char *s = "word";
    char c;
    _getline(s);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is :

```
input
word
munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

When I do the same thing in main I don't get the error, but when I try to print the string, I get a `\0`. Also when I tried to pass the pointer's address to `_getline` I got a segmentation fault. Here's that attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char _getline(char **s)
{
    char c;
    *s = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));

    int i;
    for (i = 0; (*s[i] = getchar()) != EOF && *s[i] != '\n'; ++i)
    {
        *s = (char *)realloc(*s, (i + 1) * sizeof(char));
    }
    c = *s[i];
    *s = (char *)realloc(*s, (i + 1) * sizeof(char));
    ++i;
    *s[i] = '\0';
    return c; 
}

int main()
{
    char *s = "word";
    char c;
    _getline(&s);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first attempt, you misunderstand how passing a pointer works. When you reassign `s` in `_getline`, that only affects its `s`, not `main`'s `s`, so `main` prints `word` and then tries to `free` a string literal, which predictably ends badly. To fix it, change `_getline(s)` to `_getline(&s)`, make `_getline` take a `char **` instead of a `char *`, and change all of its uses of `s` to `*s`. Note that changing all of its uses isn't a simple text replacement; in some cases, you'll have to use `(*s)` instead. For example, `s[i]` needs to become `(*s)[i]`. If you just did `*s[i]`, it would be incorrectly parsed as `*(s[i])`.

Also, you have an off-by-one error: you need to use `i + 2` when you `realloc`, not `i + 1`, since array indexing starts at 0 but the first element still takes up space.

By the way, unrelated to the error you're currently seeing, but your test for `EOF` doesn't work the way you want it to, since it's being converted to `char` before you test it, and `EOF` is outside of `char`'s range. (The exact problem depends on the signed-ness of `char`. If it's `signed`, then `\xFF` will incorrectly count as `EOF`, and if it's `unsigned`, then `EOF` won't be recognized and will incorrectly count as `\xFF`.)

Answer (score 0):

You've got a problem with `*s[i] = getchar()`.  Because of [C's operator precedence rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), the array index gets applied before the pointer dereference.  So, for example, if `i` is 1, then you'll be treating the data after `s[0]` as a pointer to a `char` and dereferencing that.  That is most likely going to be a completely invalid memory location.

What you want is `(*s)[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

Note:  `getline()` is the name of a C library function so don't use it.

The following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles.
2. performs the desired functionality.
3. properly checks for (and handles) errors.
4. avoid the problems of updating a pointer (for each character input) back in `main()` by returning a dynamic pointer and letting `main()` assign the returned pointer to a local variable.

Note: `size_t` is used for `i` because that is what `realloc()` expects for a parameter type.

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *myGetline( void )
{   
    int ch;
    char * line = NULL;

    for ( size_t i = 0; ( ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n'; ++i)
    {
        char * temp = realloc(line, i + 2);
        if( ! temp )
        {
            perror( "realloc failed" );
            free( line );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        line = temp;

        line[i] = (char)ch;
        line[i+1] = '\0';       
    }

    return line; 
}

int main( void )
{
    char *s = myGetline();
    printf("%s\n", s);
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several issues:

- Identifiers with leading underscores like `_getline` are reserved for the implementation; you should not name your functions or variables with a leading underscore.  Since `getline` is already the name of a library function, use something like `myGetline` instead.

  Remember that C passes all arguments *by value* - the formal parameter `s` in your `_getline` function is a different object in memory than the actual parameter `s` in `main`, so changes to one are not reflected in the other.  In order for a function to write to a parameter, you must pass a pointer to that parameter:

  ```
  void foo( T *ptr ) // for any type T, *including pointer types*
  {
    *ptr = new_T_value( ); // write a new value to the thing ptr points to
  }

  int main( void )
  {
    T var;
    foo( &var ); // write a new value to var
  }
  ```

  The same thing happens if `T` is a pointer type - let's replace `T` with a pointer type `P *`:

  ```
  void foo( P * *ptr ) 
  {
    *ptr = new_Pstar_value( ); // write a new value to the thing ptr points to
  }

  int main( void )
  {
    P * var;
    foo( &var ); // write a new value to var
  }
  ```

  The semantics in the two snippets are exactly the same - we're writing a new value to `var` through `*ptr`.  It's just that the `types` of `var` and `*ptr` are different.

  So in the case of your code, the prototype for `myGetline` needs to be

  ```
  void myGetline( char **s )
  ```

  and in the body of your code, you need to assign to `*s`:

  ```
  *s = malloc( sizeof **s );
  ```

  Do not cast the result of `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc` *unless* you are writing C++ (in which case you shouldn't be using the `*alloc` functions at all if you can help it) or working with an *ancient* pre-ANSI C compiler.

  Because `s` in `main` is *not* modified by `_getline`, it still points to the string literal when you pass it to `free`.  Only pointer values returned from one of the `*alloc` functions may be passed to `free`.

  `realloc` is a relatively expensive operation and can result in the buffer moving around in memory, so you don't want to do it for every character.  A better strategy is to double the buffer size as necessary, which minimizes the number of `realloc` calls.  Also, since it can return a `NULL` if it can't reallocate the buffer, you don't want to assign the result back to the original pointer - you should assign it to a temporary first and check that it isn't `NULL`, otherwise you risk losing your reference to that memory:

  ```
  void myGetline( char **s )
  {
    size_t size = 2; // size of the buffer
    size_t len  = 0; // length of the string stored in the buffer;
    char c;

    *s = malloc( sizeof **s * size );
    if ( !*s )
      return;

    while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' )
    {
      if ( len + 1 == size ) // double the buffer size
      {
        char *tmp = realloc( *s, sizeof **s * ( size * 2 ) );
        if ( !tmp )
        {
          fprintf( stderr, "Cannot extend input buffer, returning what we have so far\n" );
          return;
        }

        *s = tmp;
        size *= 2;
      }
      (*s)[len++] = c; // we want to index into what s *points to*, not s itself
      (*s)[len] = 0;   // zero terminate as we go
    }
  }
  ```